# OLE automation with C++: receiving empty variant from Invoke() instead of valid result

Tags: c++, com, invoke, ole, idispatch

In C++, I'm trying to call an OLE method which looks like this:

```
HRESULT GetFirstMono(
       [out] BSTR* name, 
       [out, retval] BSTR* monoID);
```

I use the following code to call it (adapted from http://www.codeproject.com/KB/office/MSOfficeAuto.aspx ):

```
int cArgs = 1;
DISPPARAMS dp = { NULL, NULL, 0, 0 };
DISPID dispidNamed = DISPID_PROPERTYPUT;
DISPID dispID;
VARIANT *pArgs = new VARIANT[cArgs+1];
// Extract arguments...
for(int i=0; i<cArgs; i++) {
    pArgs[i] = va_arg(marker, VARIANT);
}

// Build DISPPARAMS
dp.cArgs = cArgs;
dp.rgvarg = pArgs;

// Make the call!
    hr = pDisp->Invoke(dispID, IID_NULL, LOCALE_SYSTEM_DEFAULT, nType, &dp,
        pvResult, NULL, NULL);
    if(cArgs == 1) {
        std::cout << "oleCall()" << std::endl;
        std::cout << "vt: " << dp.rgvarg[0].vt << std::endl;
    }
```

The program excecutes without crashing, and I receive the *monoId* output BSTR* in `pvResult` (and I get the value that I expect). But instead of finding *name*, I only get an empty variant in `dp:rgvarg[0]`, i.e. on my terminal I see

```
oleCall()
vt: 0
```

. The exact same method works fine when I call it from LabView, so I figure the problem is somewhere in my code. How can I recover the *name* output?

Comment: Shouldn't `dp.cArgs` contain the value `2` (I mean`dp.cArgs = cArgs+1`)? Because the method expects two parameters. If that does not help: check the `HRESULT` return value of `Invoke`.

Comment: I'm not quite sure why, but if I set `dp.cArgs = cArgs+1`, the program crashes. As far as I can tell, the parameter marked as *retval* is returned with the variant `pvResult`; the other one should be returned via `dp`. I'm pretty sure that the result I want won't be in the HRESULT, because that's only used for error management etc.

Answer (score 0):

In case someone else is having the same problem: I wasn't able to solve it, but here's a workaround. Instead of using the `Invoke` method of the IDispatch interface, I made a header file for the interface in which `GetFirstMono` is declared, using a Microsoft program called MIDL - but one can also do it by hand (simply look up the methods of the interface with the ole/com viewer and write a corresponding header file). Then, the call to the method is quite simple:

```
BSTR name, monoId;
HRESULT hr = interfacePointer->GetFirstMono(name, monoId);
```

There's more information at [codeguru.com](http://www.codeguru.com/cpp/com-tech/activex/tutorials/article.php/c5567) . Hope it helps.

BTW: I'm still interested in the original question. If you know the answer, please post it!

Answer (score 0):

Try to set type `VT_BSTR|VT_BYREF` to argument 0.

```cpp
CComBSTR bstrName;
V_VT(&dp.rgvarg[0]) = VT_BSTR | VT_BYREF;
V_BSTRREF(&dp.rgvarg[0]) = &bstrName;
```